# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

im getting error when i tried to use subtring and charindex in my query

```
Concat('https://api.giscloud.com/1/layers/2985288/features/',f.fid,'/mosque_status_photos /',substring(f.mosque_status_photos,1,CharIndex(',',f.mosque_status_photos,0)-1),'?api_key=a2cdb99935fec159f9557b24fae90f00')
```

and also i tried case funcation bt still getting eror

```
case when isnull(f.mosque_status_photos,'0') is null
then '0' else 
Concat('https://api.giscloud.com/1/layers/2985288/features/',f.fid,'/mosque_status_photos    /',substring(f.mosque_status_photos,1,CharIndex(',',f.mosque_status_photos,0)- 1),'?api_key=a2cdb99935fec159f9557b24fae90f00') end
```

i used isnull Funcation as well bt still getting error

```
Concat('https://api.giscloud.com/1/layers/2985288/features/',f.fid,'/mosque_status_photos/',substring(isnull(f.mosque_status_photos,'0'),1,CharIndex(',',isnull(f.mosque_status_photos,'0'),0)-1),'?api_key=a2cdb99935fec159f9557b24fae90f00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your case statement is wrong for a start, it it converting all null values to '0' character and then checking if the result is null which will never be the case.

Probably what you want to something like (assuming you are looking for commas in the `mosque_status_photos` column..

```
CASE WHEN f.mosque_status_photos not like ',' 
          OR CharIndex(',',f.mosque_status_photos,0) <=1
          OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(mosque_status_photos))) = 0
     THEN '0'
     ELSE [original code for valid entries here]
     END
```